# Font size inside FilePond elements

Tags: filepond

The default styling of FilePond elements imported from the default css seems a bit small. Is there a recommended way to get to the size as seen in the examples at https://pqina.nl/filepond/?

It seems the default style in the css uses font-size of 10px.

[image: Small Fonts]

Answer (score 1):

By default the `font-size` of the FilePond root element is set to `1rem`.

You can scale it up or down by setting a different size.

```css
.filepond--root { font-size: 1.25rem; }
```

Use `em` instead of `rem` if you want to scale FilePond relatively to its parent element.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just coming across this.

if you using Filepond in a nextjs project and you're finding it difficult to apply a font-size to your Filepond component. simply add the default Filepond css to your global.css style and customize it.

for example ///global.css

`.filepond--root{font-size: 10px;}`

Answer (score 0):

I'm ok with this:

```
.filepond--root {
        font-family: inherit;
        margin-bottom: 1.5em;
        font-size: 1.3rem;
}

.filepond--root .filepond--list-scroller {
        margin-top: 0;
}
```

Font inherited from parent container so it's coherent with my app.